# npm WARN deprecated

Tags: node.js, linux, gulp, gulpjs, npm

Já tentei achar solução na net sobre esse erro e as que encontrei não funcionaram.

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve atualizar a versão do pacote no seu package.json.
Mas as vezes existem casos aonde um pacote que você esteja usando é que está usando um pacote desatualizado. De qualquer forma tente atualizar todos os pacotes que você utiliza. Se for um pacote de teceiro, corrija e abra um pull-request =)